# apt - update local package

Tags: apt, dpkg, ubuntu-16.04, deb

Some months ago I had to install `gitlab-ce` on a server with Ubuntu 16.04, no access to the public internet, so I downloaded the package from the Ubuntu repository on an other machine and then uploaded to the server and **manually installed**:

```
dpkg -i gitlab-ce.deb
```

Now the server is connected to the Web and I would like to update `gitlab-ce` as I do for any other package, that is:

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
```

I run the following command:

```
apt list --installed
```

and noticed that the gitlab-ce package is listed as a **local package**.

If that is the cause it's not updating, how can I make it **switch from local to online**?

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

For a package to be considered non-local by apt, it has to be listed in one of the repositories configured in its sources.
Have you added the GitLab Ubuntu Repository as indicated on their [download site](https://about.gitlab.com/downloads/#ubuntu1604)?

Comment: That's probably the point, I forgot to add the repository, I tought it was provided by the defaut Ubuntu repository.

I'll try asap and let you know, but I'm quite sure that it will fix my problem, thank you very much!